# How does Discord or Overwolf show games' realtime status?

Tags: discord, sdk, steam, pubg

I want to collect detailed information *(like game duration, alive count etc.)* of currently playing game on PUBG Steam.

Also the Steam has same feature. I think game provides this data to Steam by using steam_api.dll. But how overwolf or Nvidia *(example: Nvidia is able to start recording when you die or get kill with in-game overlay)* are able to collect those datas?

There is an official PUBG API but this API doesn't have the feature what I want. I don't know if it must have.

And Also Discord has an API to do this (Rich Presence) but how are others doing?

How can I collect this data for personel usage? Is there any SDK/API to do this whether official or not?

Answer (score 0):

Overwolf does this by monitoring the memory. Generally speaking, it needs to first obtain the base address of the process module in memory, and then obtain the offset of specific data.

Here's an example on the apex legend cheat engine:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/ethanedits/Apex-Legends-SDK)